# Boolean validation rSpec tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, activerecord, rspec, boolean

I'm having trouble writing a test to make sure that a field `:on_ride_photo` is a boolean value.

My validates call:

```
  validates :on_ride_photo,
    inclusion: [true, false]
```

My tests:

```
it { should validate_presence_of(:on_ride_photo) }
it { should ensure_inclusion_of(:on_ride_photo).in_array([true, false]) }
it { should_not allow_value(4).for(:on_ride_photo) }
it { should_not allow_value('lots').for(:on_ride_photo) }
```

Factory:

```
  factory :coaster do
    association :park
    name 'Nemesis'
    speed 60
    height 60
    length 160
    inversions 4
    on_ride_photo true
    lat 52.98694
    lng -1.88284
    dates_ridden '24th Jul 2013:4, 9th Aug 2009:7'
    powered false
  end
```

Errors:

> Failures:
>
> 1) Coaster validations should not allow on_ride_photo to be set to
>   "lots"
>        Failure/Error: it { should_not allow_value('lots').for(:on_ride_photo) }
>          Expected errors  when on_ride_photo is set to "lots", got no errors
>        # ./spec/models/coaster_spec.rb:98:in `block (3 levels) in '
>
> 2) Coaster validations should not allow on_ride_photo to be set to 4
>        Failure/Error: it { should_not allow_value(4).for(:on_ride_photo) }
>          Expected errors  when on_ride_photo is set to 4, got no errors
>        # ./spec/models/coaster_spec.rb:97:in `block (3 levels) in '
>
> 3) Coaster validations should not allow powered to be set to "yes"
>        Failure/Error: it { should_not allow_value('yes').for(:powered) }
>          Expected errors  when powered is set to "yes", got no errors
>        # ./spec/models/coaster_spec.rb:102:in `block (3 levels) in '
>
> 4) Coaster validations should require on_ride_photo to be set
>        Failure/Error: it { should validate_presence_of(:on_ride_photo) }
>          Expected errors to include "can't be blank" when on_ride_photo is set to nil, got errors: ["on_ride_photo is not included in the list
>   (nil)"]
>        # ./spec/models/coaster_spec.rb:95:in `block (3 levels) in '
>
> 5) Coaster validations should ensure inclusion of powered in [true,
>   false]
>        Failure/Error: it { should ensure_inclusion_of(:powered).in_array([true, false]) }
>          [true, false] doesn't match array in validation
>        # ./spec/models/coaster_spec.rb:100:in `block (3 levels) in '
>
> 6) Coaster validations should not allow powered to be set to 4
>        Failure/Error: it { should_not allow_value(4).for(:powered) }
>          Expected errors  when powered is set to 4, got no errors
>        # ./spec/models/coaster_spec.rb:101:in `block (3 levels) in '
>
> 7) Coaster validations should ensure inclusion of on_ride_photo in
>   [true, false]
>        Failure/Error: it { should ensure_inclusion_of(:on_ride_photo).in_array([true, false]) }
>          [true, false] doesn't match array in validation
>        # ./spec/models/coaster_spec.rb:96:in `block (3 levels) in '

:powered should also be a boolean field so I have the same tests for it therefore the reason why that is showing up in the test errors too.

Comment: So what exactly are you asking about? Since you haven't shown any code, I assume you're trying to write "failing tests" before writing the code to make those tests pass. If so, it's generally helpful (and helpful for getting SO help) if you focus on one test at a time.  If not, then you need to share your implementation code if anyone is going to provide any help.

Comment: Been digger further and it looks like something else is making this fail so i'll need to post a question about that and then that should help this one to get solved.